How to put global variables in environments?
I have a question regarding the management of global and local variables within the environments and with it a problem. What happens is that in the code that I show below, I want to save inside \variable the content that I say in \setvariable, so that later the content of the variable is global and I save it in \setglobalvar but in reality nothing is being saved in \variable and therefore, it is not saved in \setglobalvar.
How can I do that of first saving the content in a variable within an environment and then saving it in a global variable to use anywhere in the document?
Thank you very much for your help
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Para generar texto de ejemplo

% Definir una nueva variable global para almacenar el contenido
\newcommand{\globalvar}{}

% Comando para establecer el valor en una variable global
\newcommand{\setglobalvar}[1]{\global\edef\globalvar{#1}}
\newcommand{\variable}{}

% Definir el entorno que asigna un valor a \variable y luego lo transfiere a \globalvar
\NewEnviron{entorno}{
  \newcommand{\setvariable}[1]{\newcommand{\variable}{##1}}
  \variable
  % Paso 3: Transferir el valor de la variable local a la variable global
  \setglobalvar{\variable}
}

\begin{document}

% Usar el entorno para almacenar el contenido
\begin{entorno}
  \setvariable{holi}
\end{entorno}

% Mostrar el contenido almacenado en otro lugar
\section{Stored Content}
\globalvar

\end{document}


@cfr hi and yes, but I don't want to show the content of the environment when I called, against I want to save it content in a variable but I don't want to save the content \BODY I want to save the content in the variable that I defined

So what do you want to do with the rest of the content?

And why the two-step process? Why not just define \globalvar already?

@cfr I want to create an environment called "author" for example, there save the name, id and your email in three different variables. Then take each variable whose contents I saved in global variables and use them throughout my document

May I suggest an alternative syntax?

@cfr and of couse, if there are more than one author, I can use the enviroment again but saving the new content in a new variable, I don't know if I make myself understood

@cfr of couse, please I want all of the comments about it

See also \gdef and \xdef.  And \global\let\foo=\foo.

I think the easiest syntax for this kind of framework uses key-values for input. If you want to do this there are lots of options. One is to use the kernel's own structures, which can optionally uses expl3 to setup, but no longer requires it (see below).
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/722965/
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { manrique }
{
  name .tl_set:N = \l_manrique_name_tl, 
  name .initial:V = \c_empty_tl,
  id .tl_set:N = \l_manrique_id_tl,
  id .initial:V = \c_empty_tl,
  email .tl_set:N = \l_manrique_email_tl,
  email .initial:V = \c_empty_tl,
  tag .tl_set:N = \l_manrique_tag_tl,
  tag .initial:V = \c_empty_tl,
}
\NewDocumentCommand \entorno { +m }
{
  \group_begin:
    \tl_set_eq:NN \l_manrique_tag_tl \c_empty_tl
    \keys_set:nn { manrique } { #1 }
    \tl_if_empty:NT \l_manrique_tag_tl
    {
      \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_manrique_name_tl
      {
        \PackageError{manrique}{Tag ~ or ~ name ~ required!}{This ~ will ~ not ~ end ~ well}
      }{
        \tl_set_eq:NN \l_manrique_tag_tl \l_manrique_name_tl
      }
    }
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l_manrique_tag_tl
    {
      \clist_map_inline:nn { name , email, id }
      {
        \tl_new:c { \l_manrique_tag_tl ##1 }
        \tl_if_empty:cTF { l_manrique_ ##1 _tl }
        {
           \tl_gset:cv { \l_manrique_tag_tl ##1 } { l_manrique_ ##1 _ default _tl }
        }{
          \tl_gset:cv { \l_manrique_tag_tl ##1 } { l_manrique_ ##1 _tl }
        }
      }
    }
  \group_end:
}
\tl_new:N \l_manrique_name_default_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_manrique_name_default_tl {NAME ~ MISSING}
\tl_new:N \l_manrique_id_default_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_manrique_id_default_tl {??}
\tl_new:N \l_manrique_email_default_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_manrique_email_default_tl {UNAVAILABLE}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\entorno{tag=bob,name=William Brown,id=WB\_43a-2xy,email=brown\_w@mail.com}
\entorno{name=Tom,id=74522A,email=tom342@mail.org}
\entorno{tag=carol,name=Caroline Augusta Wilson, email=c.wilson@mail.co.uk}

\bobname's ID is \bobid{} (\bobemail)

\Tomname's ID is \Tomid{} (\Tomemail)

\carolname's ID is \carolid{} (\carolemail)
\end{document}


An alternative along the same lines would be to set up a property list for each individual, which would allow arbitrary keys to be set, together with a command for retrieving them. However, this would diverge from your intended usage later, so I'm not sure whether it would work or not.
If you want to avoid expl3, you can these days use the kernel's key-value interface without it. For example,
\makeatletter
\DeclareKeys [manrique]
{%
  name .store = \l@manrique@name,
  id .store = \l@manrique@id,
  email .store = \l@manrique@email,
  tag .store = \l@manrique@tag,
}

could be used to define equivalent keys, which can then be set with
\SetKeys [manrique] 
{%
   name = {NAME UNKNOWN},
   id   = {UNSPECIFIED ID},
   tag  = {??},
   email = \@empty,
 }
 \makeatother

and so on.
If you want to avoid key-value syntax completely, here's a version of your code which uses the environment basically to provide a group, as it doesn't really have any other purpose. The environment takes a mandatory argument which is used to construct the variable names.
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/722965/
\newcommand \setname[1]{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname \setvar name\endcsname{#1}}
\newcommand \setid[1]{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname \setvar id\endcsname{#1}}
\newcommand \setemail[1]{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname \setvar email\endcsname{#1}}
\newcommand \setvar{tag}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{entorno}{m}{%
  \renewcommand\setvar{#1}%
}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{entorno}{hol}
  \setname{holi}
  \setid{holid}
  \setemail{hol@i.day}
\end{entorno}

\section{Stored Content}
\holname's ID is \holid{} (\holemail).
\pagestyle{empty}
\end{document}



I'd exploit property lists.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definevars}{mm}
 {% #1 = tag, #2 = data
  \manrique_var_define:nn {#1} {#2}
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usevar}{mm}
 {% #1 = tag, #2 = key
  \manrique_var_use:nn {#1} {#2}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \manrique_var_define:nn
 {
  \prop_new:c {g__manrique_var_#1_prop}
  \prop_gset_from_keyval:cn {g__manrique_var_#1_prop} {#2}
 }

\cs_new:Nn \manrique_var_use:nn
 {
  \prop_item:cn {g__manrique_var_#1_prop} {#2}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definevars{bob}{
  name=William Brown,
  id=WB\_43a-2xy,
  email=brown\_w@mail.com
}
\definevars{tom}{
  name=Tom,
  id=74522A,
  email=tom342@mail.org
}
\definevars{carol}{
  name=Caroline Augusta Wilson,
  email=c.wilson@mail.co.uk
}

\begin{document}

\usevar{bob}{name}'s ID is \usevar{bob}{id}.

\usevar{carol}{name}'s email is \usevar{carol}{email}.

\end{document}


If you really want to define commands such as \bobid and \carolname, you can do it.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definevars}{mm}
 {% #1 = tag, #2 = data
  \manrique_var_define:nn {#1} {#2}
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usevar}{mm}
 {% #1 = tag, #2 = key
  \manrique_var_use:nn {#1} {#2}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \manrique_var_define:nn
 {
  \prop_new:c {g__manrique_var_#1_prop}
  \prop_gset_from_keyval:cn {g__manrique_var_#1_prop} {#2}
  \prop_map_inline:cn {g__manrique_var_#1_prop}
   {
    \cs_new:cpe { #1##1 } { \prop_item:cn {g__manrique_var_#1_prop} {##1} }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \manrique_var_use:nn
 {
  \prop_item:cn {g__manrique_var_#1_prop} {#2}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definevars{bob}{
  name=William Brown,
  id=WB\_43a-2xy,
  email=brown\_w@mail.com
}
\definevars{tom}{
  name=Tom,
  id=74522A,
  email=tom342@mail.org
}
\definevars{carol}{
  name=Caroline Augusta Wilson,
  email=c.wilson@mail.co.uk
}

\begin{document}

\usevar{bob}{name}'s ID is \usevar{bob}{id}.

\bobname's ID is \bobid.

\usevar{carol}{name}'s email is \usevar{carol}{email}.

\carolname's email is \carolemail.

\end{document}


